# how to get visitor's UTC time not relying on store view time zone?

Tags: magento-1.9, timezone

It is required to convert customer's (or guest visitor time zone) into UTC 0 to properly store in in database in `timestamp` column. In magento this often doing by relying on certain store view timezone.

Is there any builtin magento functions to get visitors time in UTC 0, or to get timezone to convert it into proper format ?

If you have other solution than to get timezone over JS and convert it manually on the backend, would much helpful as I just dont wont to reinvent the wheel.